# how to call activity from service?

Tags: android

I have created two projects. One project will act as a library and another as a main project. I will call the main project to library project, then the library project will send a notification. It's working fine but my question is if i click the notification it will go to main project activity. What can i do? Is it possible in android?

In library project :

```
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent("com.sample.myapp.Monitor"), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Start Scheduler")
            .setContentText("Please start your activity!")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1, 1);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

here the com.sample.myapp.Monitor is main project activity.If i click the notification it does not call main project activity.

Comment: Are you talking about notification in notifications drawer? And what exactly do you want to happen when user taps on that notification?

Comment: I have created two projects app A and app B.B is android library project and i have been connected B from A .Here B will send notification,if i click the notification it will start the activity which is in A.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried to do yourself about this? What haven't worked as you've expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution to connect my library project to main project activity.

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExampleActivity"));
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, so you want to create a notification and when user clicks it you want to show him your Activity, right? In this case you can read [Google documentation about that](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action)

EDIT: [Here](https://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/) you can look a good example of creating a Service with BroadcastReceiver. I assume that your library does some background processing (perhaps in Service as well). So I would suggest the following scenario:

1. Your application starts a service with registered BroadcastReceiver
2. Your library project does some background processing and after that sends a broadcast as described in the example provided.
3. Previosely registered BroadcastReceiver receives a broadcast and sends a notification with action pointing to your Activity (as described in the developer page from my original answer)
4. User click notification and Activity opens.

Comment: I have created two projects app A and app B.B is android library project and i have been connected B from A .Here B will send notification,if i click the notification it will start the activity which is in A.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to create notification from your library project? As for me user interaction should be quite unique in different applications. Have you considered sending a broadcast from you library, so your main project can receive that broadcast and create a notification?

Comment: Sure, please see edit to my answer. Unfortunately I can't write a code for that at the moment, but if you have some problems I can write it later in the evening